# Make an ArrayList of BufferedImages, Keeps Crashing

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, converters, bufferedimage

SOLVED

I am making an java game. I'm trying to get text converted in BufferedImages that are mine tiles. But every time i get an error and i don't know what is wrong.

I hope you can help me.

```
package my.tdl.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import my.project.gop.main.SpriteSheet;
import my.project.gop.main.loadImageFrom;

public class Font {

private static String chars = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,?!:'1234567890 ";
public ArrayList<BufferedImage> msg_img = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
public static SpriteSheet text = new SpriteSheet();

public Font(String msg, Color colour) {
    text.setSpriteSheet(loadImageFrom.LoadImageFrom(Main.class, "textSheet.png"));
    msg.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println(msg.length());

    for (int i = 0; i <= msg.length() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        int charIndex = chars.indexOf(msg.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(chars.charAt(charIndex));
        if (charIndex > 0) {
            System.out.println(charIndex * 16 + ", 0, 16, 16");
            BufferedImage image = text.getTile(charIndex * 16, 0, 16, 16);
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(colour);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            msg_img.add(image);
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<BufferedImage> getMsg_img() {
    return msg_img;
}

}
```

this is the output:

```
STARTGAME
9
0
S
304, 0, 16, 16
1
T
320, 0, 16, 16
2
A
16, 0, 16, 16
3
R
288, 0, 16, 16
4
T
320, 0, 16, 16
5
G
112, 0, 16, 16
6
A
16, 0, 16, 16
7
M
208, 0, 16, 16
8
E
80, 0, 16, 16
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at my.tdl.gamestate.GameStateButton.render(GameStateButton.java:87)
at my.tdl.gamestates.MenuState.render(MenuState.java:38)
at my.tdl.gamestate.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:22)
at my.tdl.gameloop.Gameloop.render(Gameloop.java:37)
at my.project.gop.main.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm trying to convert the string="STARTGAME"

Sorry for the bad enlish.

if you need more of the code send me a message and i will send you it.

I solved it myself. I did a stupid thing and putted =< in the GameStateButton class.

greetings, bjkalk

Comment: Please provide the class `GameStateButton` and method `render`, especially line 87.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= msg.length() + 1; i++) {
```

Should read

```
   for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
```

Otherwise you will always read the 10th element (element nine) in a 9 element message. Remember the 9 elements are numbered 0 to 8. In fact with the +1 you will be looking for the 11th element.

By the way I also noticed that you are doing the following call and throwing away the result.

```
    msg.toUpperCase();
```

perhaps you intended

```
  msg = msg.toUpperCase();
```